# Flyway execution SELECT [*]VALUE syntax error with h2 when strat Spring-boot Application

Tags: spring-boot, h2, flyway

I faced below error when run Flyway enables with h2.

**versions:**

```
Spring Boot v2.7.8, Spring v5.3.25
"flyway", "7.2.1"
"h2", "2.1.214"
```

**applcation yaml:**

```
spring:
  cache:
    enabled: false
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:ppyDB;MODE=Oracle
    username: sa
    password: 
    driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
  flyway:
    enabled: true
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:myDB;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
    baseline-on-migrate: true
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect

  h2:
    console:
      enabled: true
      path: /h2-console
```

Application start-up error

**Error:**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flyway' defined in class path resource [myapp/config/FlywayConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.flywaydb.core.internal.exception.FlywaySqlException: 
Unable to determine H2 compatibility mode
-----------------------------------------
SQL State  : 42001
Error Code : 42001
Message    : Syntax error in SQL statement "SELECT [*]VALUE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SETTINGS WHERE NAME = 'MODE'"; expected "DISTINCT, ALL, *, INTERSECTS (, NOT, EXISTS, UNIQUE, INTERSECTS"; SQL statement:
SELECT VALUE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SETTINGS WHERE NAME = 'MODE' [42001-214]

Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement "SELECT [*]VALUE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SETTINGS WHERE NAME = 'MODE'"; expected "DISTINCT, ALL, *, INTERSECTS (, NOT, EXISTS, UNIQUE, INTERSECTS"; SQL statement:
SELECT VALUE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SETTINGS WHERE NAME = 'MODE' [42001-214]
```

However if strat up the application without h2 (instead using Oracle DB) see the below error

**Error:**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flyway' defined in class path resource [myapp/config/FlywayConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.flywaydb.core.internal.license.FlywayEditionUpgradeRequiredException: Flyway Teams Edition or Oracle upgrade required: Oracle 12.1 is no longer supported by Flyway Community Edition, but still supported by Flyway Teams Edition.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620)
.....
Caused by: org.flywaydb.core.internal.license.FlywayEditionUpgradeRequiredException: Flyway Teams Edition or Oracle upgrade required: Oracle 12.1 is no longer supported by Flyway Community Edition, but still supported by Flyway Teams Edition.
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.database.base.Database.ensureDatabaseNotOlderThanOtherwiseRecommendUpgradeToFlywayEdition(Database.java:165)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.database.oracle.OracleDatabase.ensureSupported(OracleDatabase.java:84)
```

Comment: Flyway 7.2.1 is too old and cannot be used for new versions of H2 database. And Oracle 12.1 is too old and even this old version of Flyway doesn't support it already, you need a commercial version of Flyway to work with it.

Comment: @EvgenijRyazanov Is there compatibale version of H2 with others? Other thing was when I tried with latest Flyway (i.e. `9.16.1`) I get `Validate failed: Migrations have failed validation`

Comment: It's just a common error message, you need to check the list of failed migrations to figure out the actual problem.

Comment: @EvgenijRyazanov I ran `gradlew.bat flywayRepair` from comandline by setting `flyway.enabled=false` from `application.yaml` with latest h2/flyway version and it was a success. However I can't see new tables in h2. Do you have any clue?

Comment: Sorry it was my bad, it has to be `gradlew.bat flywayMigrate`. So I get synatx issues there. Looks like H2 syntax are bit different to Oracle(which is the one we use in the actual application. H2 is just for system testing step) . So I asume `Validate failed: Migrations have failed validation` I got before due to these synatx issues.